# Redirect stderr to stdout without also redirecting to a file?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

Is there a way to redirect stderr to stdout, so that all stderr output is received in stdout, but without also redirecting to a file?

There are of course a number of ways of redirecting stderr to stdout and then outputting the combined stream to a file, but in this case I want all of the output to just come through stdout without any files being involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you want to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and print `stdout` to terminal?

If, so:

```
command 2>&1
```

where:

```
0 = stdin
1 = stdout
2 = stderr
```

`2>&1` means: redirect `stderr` into `stdout`

you can also do:

`2>filename`

Comment: I tried that and got an error about a missing file, but tried it again and it worked. Must've typed the wrong character or something!